# Saving An Image file to Assets folder in React App

Tags: node.js, reactjs

I am trying to upload a image in my react app and save it in my assets folder.
I have the DataUrl for the image , but when i am trying to write the dataurl to an image file using fs.writefile(), i am getting below error

```
var normalizeFilePath = (path: string) => (path.startsWith('file://') ? path.slice(7) : path);
|
| type MkdirOptions = {



  ModuleParseError: Module parse failed: Unexpected token (30:29)
  You may need an appropriate loader to handle this file type, currently no loaders are configured to process this file. See ht  tps://webpack.js.org/concepts#loaders
  | };
```

my application is a gatsby -react Application.
on clicking the submit button , submit handler is called to write the data to file.

```
    const submitHandler = (event) => {
        console.log(event.target);
        console.log(files.target);
fs.writeFile(`../assets/images/testimonialImage/${files.target.files[0].name}.png`, files.target.files[0], function (err) {
  if (err) throw err;
  console.log('Replaced!');
}); 
    }
```

Tried using saveAs function but its downloading file to downloads folder.

What i need is , when i upload the file in frontend , it should save it in the assets/image folder.
As i am not having any backend for my app.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your approach of uploading a file in frontend and saving it to `assets/image` is only going to work in a development environment. If you want it to work in production environment too, you NEED a backend. It could be a simple node.js server which saves the file to a folder.